# Duplicate values in dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, dictionary, dirichlet

I have a problem where after the outer loop ends, both dictionaries point to the same values. I have code of the sort:

```
for state in states:
    probab_dist = numpy.random.dirichlet(some args..).flatten()
    for i, j in zip(word, range(len(word))):
        state.dict[i] = probab_dist[j]
```

I inserted a print statement after line 2 to see whether the dirichlet function just returns the same value every single time. It didn't, and sure enough printing the value of the dictionary of each state after the inner loop exits showed that at first each state's dictionary has its own values.

I figured it might be a deep copy vs shallow copy kind of problem so I replaced line 4 with `state.dict[i] = copy.deepcopy(probab_dist[j]`, but that didn't change anything.

Any ideas what I could try next?

Comment: I think you can replace that `zip` with [`enumerate`,](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=enumerate#enumerate) a built-in that returns an integer index along with each element in the iterable.

Comment: Did you mean mean replace the `range(len())`? If so, thanks, I replaced it. Any idea how I can deal with my other problem?

Comment: No, sorry. In fact, I'm unclear on what the problem is. What is `probab_dist[j]`? Isn't it a number?

Comment: Also, seems like you could just zip up the word and the probab_dist array to get your key/value pairs: `state.dict = {k:v for k,v in zip(word, probab_dist)}`

Comment: Yes, it's a list of numbers. The first time the loop runs, the value of probab_dist is `[ 0.06690239  0.58836214  0.09368838  0.09415571  0.15689137]`, and when I check the values of the first state's dictionary at the end of the outer loop, it is also the same. The second time the loop runs, the value of probab_dist is `[ 0.07864053  0.20966494  0.04294388  0.04541454  0.62333611]`, and the second state's dictionary has that value.

However, once the loop exits, both states' dictionaries default to the second state's values.

Comment: My guess is that at assignment time, in line 4, a shallow copy was performed instead of a deep copy. As such, both the first state and the second state pointed to a place in memory, whose values got updated the second time the run loops.

Comment: Actually, once I replaced the inner loop with the zip up you suggested, the problem disappeared. I am still not sure why. Thanks so much, though!

Comment: That's fascinating. As a favor to the `numpy` community, would you try to reproduce that behavior with like two lines of code? That is, `v1 = ...flatten()` and `v2 = ... flatten()`. It's possible you've discovered a bug wherein some variable is being re-used. (The obvious suspect is the "parameter default = []" bug that we all commit at some point.)